# Magento admin login session expires untimely when clearing caches by "Flush cache storage"

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, cache, session

Exactly same issue as in the title here in Magento 1.9.2.4 ce running website.

Checked and set the cookie path and domain in database and also checked session timeout, all is ok.

What could be the issue behind this ?

Comment: How sessions are handled : files, db, memcached, redis? How Magento cache is configured : files, db?

Comment: Sessions are handled by "files", also cleared the sessions folder and rechecked umpteen times, but still same issue over and over again.